# How to check facebook permission using javascript sdk v2.1?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In older javascript sdk it's working fine after integrated new sdk it's showing undefined query message in console.

`function check_permissions (permissions, uid, cb){
      FB.Data
        .query('select {0} from permissions where uid={1}', permissions, uid)
        .wait(function (res) {
          if (!res || res.length < 1) return cb(false);
          var row = res[0];
          var aperm = permissions.split(',');
          for (var i = 0; i < aperm.length; i++) {
            if (row[aperm[i]] != 1) return cb(false);
          }
          return cb(true);
      });
}
check_permissions("my permission","my is","callback");`

Answer (score 1):

There's no `.query()` method in the JS SDK (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/v2.1), so what are you using?

You can call `/me/permissions` with the respective access token to see whcih permissions the user gave to the app.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/permissions

Comment: Is there any method available so we can directly check (public_profile,email,video_upload,publish_stream) comma seprated action with FB.<<methid name>>?

Comment: No, there isn't. Please read the docs. BTW, there's no permission called `video_upload`